# Javascript closure not working as expected in for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

I have this page, where we have three menus

```
<ul class="support-menu nav navbar-nav nav_menu nav nav-pills nav-stacked full-width">
        <li class="nav_menu"><a href="#" id="manage">Manage</a></li>
        <li class="nav_menu"><a href="#" id="asset">Asset</a></li>
        <li class="nav_menu"><a href="#" id="report">Report</a></li>
</ul>
```

On the document ready, following code is written

```
 $(function() {
     var actionUrlMap = {
        manage: "/support/manage",
        asset: "/support/asset",
        report: "/support/report"
    };
    var loadUrl = function (url) {
        $("#resultDiv").load(url);
    };
    for (var prop in actionUrlMap) {
        $("body").on("click", "#" + prop, function (e) {
            loadUrl(actionUrlMap[prop]);
        });
    };
});
```

But no matter which menu I click, I always get the page

`Welcome to Report Support Section`

**It looked to me that the problem is related with closure, so I changed the code to following**

```
for (var prop in actionUrlMap) {
        var localProp = prop;
        var localUrl = actionUrlMap[localProp];
        $("body").on("click", "#" + localProp, function (e) {
            loadUrl(localUrl);
        });
    };
```

I thought that **now since I am capturing the local variable, it should load the correct url, but click on any of the menu options still loads the**

`Welcome to Report Support Section`

**I also tried this**

```
for (var prop in actionUrlMap) {
        $("body").on("click", "#" + prop, function (e) {
            var localProp = prop;
            var localUrl = actionUrlMap[localProp];
            loadUrl(localUrl);
        });
    };
```

Again, thinking that **now I have captured the property in local variable, it should load the correct url, but it is still loading the report help section**.

What am I missing here? Am I understanding the whole closure concept wrong? Or something else is missing from the code?

Comment: As an alternative you can  do `loadUrl(actionUrlMap[this.id.replace('#', '')]);`

Comment: @Satpal: Yes, I know I can, but that's not the point. I want to know what am I missing with this closure related thing.

Comment: "*What am I missing here?*" - the closure is the `function`, and it captures the `prop` variable (and `actionUrlMap` and `loadUrl`, but those don't change their value). `localProp` and `localUrl` are just local variables.

Comment: Try taking this function `var loadUrl = function (url) { $("#resultDiv").load(url);  };` outside the `.ready` block